# OAuth2 token with google play services on Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage, google-play-services

I'm attempting to get a Oauth2 token for Google Cloud Storage on Android using Google Play services.  I am using the following code

```
try {
        gsToken=GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, email,
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userAuthEx) {
            startActivityForResult(userAuthEx.getIntent(),1);;
    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {

    }
```

This throws a GoogleAuthException.  Is this scope not supported at this time by Google PLay Services??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix the scope with the string "oauth2:" when asking GoogleAuthUtil for OAuth2 tokens. If you want multiple scopes you can list them with a space separator.

So, in your case the scope string would be "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only".

For more details see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html.

Comment: Hey @jham, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Comment: hey, I'm having the exact same issue, GoogleAuthUtil.getToken was working fine previously, and recently it starts giving Unknown exception. Have you found a solution?